# How to setup PROD and DEV enviorment on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So i have a lambda function say `function`
I have created an alias named `DEV` pointing to `$LATEST`
now i want to create an alias named `PROD` pointing to some other version
Issue here is that i don't know how to publish a new version of lambda which i can point to using `PROD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Click on Actions at the top of the window.
- Select "Publish New Version"
- Give description and save.
- Now click on Actions and select "create alias".
- Name the alias as dev and point it to the version you just created.
- Repeat process for prod (replace code or Environment variables)